# Query Elasticsearch index with postman returns schema

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I tried using postman to query the ES index by setting header:

Content-Type: application/json

and the query as follows:

[image]

I got the schema as the result returned from the query.
How can I get the data in the returned message?

Comment: You need to use the `_search` endpoint, try `https://elastic-ip:9200/index-name/_search`

Comment: @leandrojmp:That helps. Thanks !